# [Minitab 16]Regression: How we can Ignore Outliers in a regression analyses?

Tags: regression, minitab

I want to draw a simple linear regression chart in Minitab and I want to find The regression equation. I use two column of data and this path:
Stat>>Regression>>Regression...
Minitab shows me outliers in the results but it doesn't give me the correct equation!!
I want to ignore these Outliers without deleting rows.
so what I can do about this??
Here is a picture of my question:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work for Minitab and I checked with our tech support team about your question. Unfortunately, there isn't a way to exclude outliers yet in Minitab, but I've submitted this request to our feedback team on your behalf.

If you'd still like to remove the outliers from your data set, look at the table of unusual observations, then subset based on the row number that the unusual observation is located in.

If you have further questions, don't hesitate to contact our tech support team at http://www.minitab.com/support/